# Trying to predict numbers in a LSTM and having extremely high loss (even with MinMax Scaler and Dropout)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

```
from numpy import array
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dropout
from keras.layers import Dense

def split_univariate_sequence(sequence, n_steps_in, n_steps_out):
    X, y = list(), list()
    for i in range(len(sequence)):
        # find the end of this pattern
        end_ix = i + n_steps_in
        out_end_ix = end_ix + n_steps_out
        # check if we are beyond the sequence
        if out_end_ix > len(sequence):
            break
        # gather input and output parts of the pattern
        seq_x, seq_y = sequence[i:end_ix], sequence[end_ix:out_end_ix]
        X.append(seq_x)
        y.append(seq_y)
    return array(X), array(y)

n_steps_in, n_steps_out = 30, 30

X1, y1 = split_univariate_sequence(sumpred, n_steps_in, n_steps_out)

transformer = MinMaxScaler()
X1_transformed = transformer.fit_transform(X1)

n_features = 1
X1_transformed = X1_transformed.reshape((X1_transformed.shape[0], X1_transformed.shape[1], n_features))

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(150, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(n_steps_in, n_features)))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(n_steps_out))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

model.fit(X1_transformed, y1, epochs=1000, verbose=1)

# demonstrate prediction
x_input = sumpred[-30:].reshape(1, -1)
x_input = transformer.transform(x_input)
x_input = x_input.reshape((1, n_steps_in, n_features))
yhat = model.predict(x_input, verbose=1)

yhat_inverse = transformer.inverse_transform(yhat)
```

`sumpred` is a array of float-32 (144,) with values between 390.624 to 347471. I'm trying to predict the next 30 numbers based on the last 30 `sumpred` values.

When I train the model, I have results like this:

```
Epoch 990/1000
85/85 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1031220211.9529
Epoch 991/1000
85/85 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1087168440.4706
Epoch 992/1000
85/85 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1011368153.6000
Epoch 993/1000
85/85 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1104842800.1882
Epoch 994/1000
85/85 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1086514331.1059
Epoch 995/1000
85/85 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1050088100.8941
Epoch 996/1000
85/85 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1003426751.2471
Epoch 997/1000
85/85 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1139417025.5059
Epoch 998/1000
85/85 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1129283814.4000
Epoch 999/1000
85/85 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1107968009.0353
Epoch 1000/1000
85/85 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1651960831.6235
```

The values in `yhat_inverse` are far beyond expected. It was not better with other losses, like mean squared logarithmic error. Even with the data transformation (`MinMaxScaler`) and `Dropout` layers, I'm still having this issue.

Someone has any clue to improve my model performance?

Answer (score 0):

Your model is not able to learn, so, first increase the size of the network. Given how much the loss is coming out, the input size is quite large and you are not providing enough power to the neural network to learn the data.

Remove the dropouts first and just increase the layers and keep them all at 150 or more.

Dropout is usually used towards the end when you see overfitting, but, your model has not even started learning.

Comment: Tried this, with no success. Change my model to [this](https://pastebin.com/NFhKYJ5S)(trained with models with more layers, also), but the problem persists.

Comment: I have big values in my vector sumpred. Can this can impact the value of the loss function?